# Как удалить папки _notes из всех подпапок во всех ветках за всю историю?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

Как удалить папки `_notes` из всех подпапок во всех ветках за всю историю?

Comment: Удалить в одной ветке и смёрджить это в другие ветки.

Comment: Возможно [bfg](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) - это то, что вам нужно

Answer (score 3):

Основываясь на примере из руководства [**git-filter-branch**(1)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_examples), команда будет выглядеть как-то так.

```
git filter-branch \
    --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch '*_notes' '**/*_notes'" \
    -- --all
```

Расшифровка: переписываем историю хранилища, вызывая фильтр индекса. Аргумент для `--index-filter` - это обычная команда оболочки, которая изменяет состояние индекса. В данном случае удаляются файлы, подпадающие под шаблоны `*_notes` или `**/*_notes`. То есть оканчивающиеся на `_notes` в корне хранилица и во вложенных каталогах. Обратите внимание на комбинацию кавычек - двойные кавычки передают обычную строку самому Git, который затем вызывает оболочку, и она не раскрывает звёздочки (т.к. они в одинарных кавычках), этим занимается Git и более эфективно. `--all` - ключ для выборки всех фиксаций, которые существуют в вашем хранилище.

Comment: Не получилось. Вложенные папки так точно на месте остались.

Comment: странно... у меня вот удалилось; что вывела команда у вас? (мой вывод: https://paste.ubuntu.com/25747380/)

Comment: `_notes` — это само название папки, а не окончание названия. Эти папки создал в своё время Dreamweaver. Долго снова делать по всей истории проход, чтобы показать точный текст результата, но скажу, что без `*` непосредственно перед  `_notes` git нашёл только две папки в корне. В подпапках — вообще ничего не видит.

Comment: проблема где-то на вашей стороне https://paste.ubuntu.com/25757319/